# Terminal velocity of a magnet on a copper pipe

Tags: electromagnetism

If a permanent magnet is dropped down a vertical copper pipe, it eventually reaches a terminal velocity even if there is no air resistance. Why should this be?

Comment: -1 This sounds like a homework type question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Note: "Terminal" velocity is _constant_ velocity.  Constant velocity means zero acceleration. Zero acceleration means zero net force: There must be some force acting on the magnet that exactly cancels the force due to gravity. You need to find out the nature of that force—why and when it exactly opposes gravity.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question lacks basic prior research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Because while the magnet drops, it induces currents in the copper pipe, and in turn produces a magnetic field that exerts magnetic force opposing the movement of the magnet.
Like air resistance, this magnetic force will eventually be as strong as gravity and thus net force on magnet becomes zero so the magnet reaches a terminal velocity

check out this video where the exact thing you are talking about is done.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7Rg0TcHQ4Y